# python regex split function equivalent in golang

Tags: python, regex, go, regex-group

I've below python code to match regex::

```
import re
digits_re = re.compile("([0-9eE.+]*)")

p = digits_re.split("Hello, where are you 1.1?")

print(p)
```

It gives this output::
 
`['', '', 'H', 'e', '', '', 'l', '', 'l', '', 'o', '', ',', '', ' ', '', 'w', '', 'h', 'e', '', '', 'r', 'e', '', '', ' ', '', 'a', '', 'r', 'e', '', '', ' ', '', 'y', '', 'o', '', 'u', '', ' ', '1.1', '', '', '?', '', '']`

I'm trying to get the above output with `golang`.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    // Execute the command and get the output
    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "Hello, where are you 1.1?")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Extract the numerical values from the output using a regular expression
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`([0-9eE.+]*)`)
    //matches := re.FindAllString(out.String(), -1)
    splits := re.Split(out.String(), -1)
    fmt.Println(splits)

}
```

I get output like below::

```
[H l l o ,   w h r   a r   y o u   ? 
]
```

I think regex is language dependant, so `split()` function used in python won't be helpful with `golang`. Having used multiple `Find*()` functions part of `regexp` package but couldn't find one which could provide the output of the above python program.

The goal of the output string array is to separate characters that can't be converted to `float` & if a string can be parsed to float, I calculate the moving average.

In the end, I combine everything & present output like Linux `watch` command.

Shall you need more details/context? I would be glad to share.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Regexp in Go and Python differ, for example Go does not support negative lookahead, I'm guessing the difference is because of what they support (due to the large number of empty strings in the Python example). Anyway the matching you have in Python seems strange and not useful anyway, I think it might make more sense to look form numbers with something like `\d+(\.\d+)*([Ee]\d+)*` and then use `re.FindAllString`.

Comment: I could extract the `float64`/`scientific` numerical from the string. I'm not comfortable with python, hence doing a literal translation of [mmwatch](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-blog/blob/master/2017-06-29-ssdp/mmwatch). As you can see there, line 44 has some function to validate whether a string can be parsed to float or not. 
The format with empty strings is used while assembling the output back. Am I right here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I got something which works for my use case. It's not exactly in the same format as `python` but without empty strings/chars.

I used both `Split` & `FindAllString` functions to get desired output.

```
    // unfortunately go regex Split doesn't work like python
    // so we construct the entire array with matched string (numericals)
    // and the split strings to combine the output
    splits := digitsRe.Split(string(out), -1)
    matches := digitsRe.FindAllString(string(out), -1)

    p := []string{}
    for i := 0; i < len(splits); i++ {
        p = append(p, matches[i])
        p = append(p, splits[i])
    }
```

With above snippet, I get something like ::

```
[H e l l o ,   w h e r e   a r e   y o u  1.1 ?]
```

I'm not that good with `regex`, somehow the above one works for my use case.

On a lighter note, I heard a joke from my colleague that if you are solving a problem with the help of `regex`, you will end up with two problems!!!

Answer (score -1):

To match the given output, pls see if this helps you.

```
import re
p = re.sub(r"[0-9eE.+]", "", "Hello, where are you 1.1?")
p = [p] 
# p = list(p) ## based on your requirement
print(p)
```

Comment: I need it in golang. python was a reference.